# Parse server dashboard shows me white blank screen

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-platform

I setup the parse server using npm install parse dashboard and then set my appId ,masterkey and server url in the parse-dashboard using cmd and it generates a url http://0.0.0.0:4040/. But after showing some red ,green and blue dots ,a permanent blank screen comes. I tried some solutions that I found on internet but nothing worked for me. So if someone knows about this pls help me with this.

This is the parse dashboard page screenshot:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbk1z.png

Comment: I had that same problem, I will ask my brother how we solved it and come back to you as soon as I know the answer.

Comment: Where's Parse Server running? On your local machine or a remote server?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Parse server is running on aws and I am trying to connect my android project with it.

Comment: It looks you have some misconfiguration in your dashboard config. You should be using AWS server address, and not 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

http://

instead of https://

it worked for me

Comment: Why? Which URL in the question should be changed from https to http?

Comment: When u start the instance
You will get a "Public IPv4 address/DNS"
that URL...should be changed in your browser